# Regarding Storage on Cloudera CDH 4.6 on Amazon EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I am planning on installing Cloudera CDH 4.6 on two m1.large instances in a VPC. Cloudera provides EC2-specific instructions here: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_on_EC2.html

As noted in the instructions, *"Instances provisioned on AWS EC2 by this wizard are instance store-based, so all data will be lost when an instance is stopped or terminated."*

I am going to be starting and stopping the instances frequently. I don't care about retaining the data stored in HBase on the HDFS, but would I need to re-install Cloudera after each instance start? It is not clear to me whether the install and its configuration would be preserved or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your configuration is gone after you terminate your `instance-store` type of instance. So every time you add new instances to the cluster or you create new cluster the Cloudera Manager has to reinstall everything it needs to get something up and running (depending on the role of the server: hdfs, hive, hbase, namenode, datanode, etc)

If you need custom and specific configuration you should probably look at using custom AMIs (which Cloudera Manager lets you). However, for more flexibility instead of creating an `instance-store` AMI you should probably create an `EBS backed` AMI. This type of AMIs/instances will allow you to stop/restart/create snapshots/create another AMI. Also, if you want to take advantage of ephemeral storage (faster) you can also create an `EBS backed` AMI that has ephemeral storage as an additional device.

Answer (score 0):

While one can technically create a hadoop cluster on AWS using EBS backed instances, one must note that doing so prevents data locality that is the basis of hadoop architecture. With EBS backed instances, you force the data read/writes in map reduce jobs to make network travels.

Why? Because EBS stores are in reality network attached drives. Any read/writes by the MR jobs on a data node will make bits to travel back and forth between the RAM of the data node and the network drives.

Ephemeral/Instance stores are local virtual disks attached to that EC2 instance, and are therefore fastest. Also if you are using HS1 EC2 instance, the instance stores are optimized for sequential reads, which is what hadoop does.

EBS stores are optimized for random IO, and therefore sequential IO will suffer while running hadoop jobs.

Thats the trade off.